# Find the last index of the first match in Java

Tags: java, regex, find, match

Lets say I have this string

```
String s ="stackjomvammssastackvmlmvlrstack"
```

And I want to find the last index of the first match of the substring "stack" which is (index=)4 in my example.

How will I do that?

Here's what I have done so far

```
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);
    int i=0;
    while (m.find())
    {    
        System.out.println(m.start());
        System.out.println(m.end());
    }
```

But that displays the last index of the last match.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to match?

Comment: What's the "first match" ?

Comment: @assylias and Brian sorry, im looking for the word "stack"

Comment: What have you done already? Do you know how to find the index of the start of the word? If you solve that, the rest is easy. I've downvoted because I see no evidence of prior research or effort on your part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply find the position of the word and add its length:

```
String s = "stackjomvammssastackvmlmvlrstack";
String match = "stack";
int start = s.indexOf(match);
int end = (start + match.length() - 1);
System.out.println(match + " found at index " + start);
System.out.println("Index of last character of first match is " + end);
```

If you need to use a regex, your code is close to the solution - you could do this:

```
String s = "stackjomvammssastackvmlmvlrstack";
String match = "s.*?k";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(match).matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.end() - 1);
}
```

Comment: @Kent The op did not mention that he wanted to use regexes.

Comment: the code block has `Matcher, Pattern...` also the tag `regex`

Comment: Hi. I want to use regex. but I made it simple in my example. Thank you for this

Comment: @srhsnl I have added a version with a regex.

Comment: @Kent `"s.*k"` will match the entire string and `m.end()` will return the length of the string. To only get the first match the OP needs to use a non greedy version.

Comment: @assylias you are right, I just made the example to show the indexOf version doesn't work with regex.  `s.*k` could match x len, but the string has only 4 of length.

Comment: I already tried to use m.end() but it gives me the last index of the last match. I need to get the last index of the first match.

Comment: @srhsnl What regex are you using?

Comment: @srhsnl try to change your while loop to if. as in this answer and my answer suggested. with while loop, you should have 3 pairs of output (start/end), don't just look the last one.

Comment: @srhsnl And the string you are matching? Note that you need to escape the period and should probably use a non-greedy wildcard: `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("http://.*?\\.img")`.

Comment: @assylias  Ok. I changed it already. Pattern p = Pattern.compile("http://.*\\.html") and look in view-source of this url http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html

Comment: @srhsnl Once again, you need to use a non greedy wild card: `.*?` or it will match only one string. So `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("http://.*?\\.html")`

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
if (m.find())
        System.out.println(m.end() - 1);
```

from java doc of Matcher.end():

```
Returns the offset after the last character matched.
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right, you are trying to find the first match of "stack", and then get the last index....

You can accomplish this by doing:

```
string toFind = "stack";
int firstOccurance = s.indexOf(toFind); (being s the word you posted above)
int whatYourLooking = firstOccurance + toFind.length() - 1;
```

Hope it helps! ;)

Comment: Hi, the word to find is not definite. I made some changes to my question. But thank you for this.

Comment: Hi, the word to find is not definite. I made some changes to my question. But thank you for this.

Answer (score 0):

This way?

```
String s ="stackjomvammssastackvmlmvlrstack";
String word = "stack";
int index = s.indexOf(word) + word.length() - 1;
```

Comment: Hi, the word to find is not definite. I made some changes to my question. But thank you for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
final String input = "stackjomvammssastackvmlmvlrstack";
final String stack = "stack";
int start = input.indexOf(stack);
int end = start + stack.length() - 1;
```

Comment: Hi, the word to find is not definite. I made some changes to my question. But thank you for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "stackjomvammssastackvmlmvlrstack";
```

String stack = "stack";
        int index = s.indexOf(stack) + stack.length();

Comment: Hi, the word to find is not definite. I made some changes to my question. But thank you for this.

Answer (score -1):

im edited my previous answer

```
  String s ="stackjomvammssastackvmlmvlrstack";      
  String pattern = "stack";

Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);
int i=0;
while (m.find())
{    
    System.out.println(m.start());
    System.out.println(m.start()+m.length());
}
```

Comment: This would have been a better answer with a code sample, rather than pseudo-code.